# why the Vue suggest use v-if not $destroy to destroy a component

Tags: vue.js

Why the Vue suggest use v-if not $destroy to destroy a component.In Vue document,it said like this:

In normal use cases you shouldn’t have to call this method yourself. Prefer controlling the lifecycle of child components in a data-driven fashion using v-if and v-for.

From  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#vm-destroy  :

> vm.$destroy() Usage:
>
> Completely destroy a vm. Clean up its connections with other existing
> vms, unbind all its directives, turn off all event listeners.
>
> Triggers the beforeDestroy and destroyed hooks.
>
> In normal use cases you shouldn’t have to call this method yourself.
> Prefer controlling the lifecycle of child components in a data-driven
> fashion using v-if and v-for.

Answer (score 0):

You should not manually destroy your components - Vue will take care of this. If you try to destroy them by yourself - it may confuse Vue.

V-IF destroys and recreates the component depending on its argument. The idea is that instead of imperatively creating/destroying components you instead declaratively specify in your template when the component should be created and when - destroyed.

It is about `declarative` vs `imperative` style of programming.

Comment: Not compare v-show with v-if.I want to know v-if="false" to destroy a component with $destroy to destroy a component  difference.

Comment: So, the vm instance is still in the memory?just not render the vm?how can i see if the vm instance is still in the memory,just not render?I print console in parent component to see this.$children,i found that, v-if and $destroy all make the this.$children empty。

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. V-IF actually destroys (and recreates) the component.

Comment: so,they are the same?

Comment: Only 50% - `$destroy` will destroy the component but V-IF will automatically recreate it if the argument is TRUE.